# Hive query execution for custom udf is exepecting hdfs jar path instead of local path in CDH4 with Oozie flow

Tags: oozie

We are migrating from CDH3 to CDH4 and as part of this migration we are moving all the jobs that we have on CDH3. We have noticed one critical issue in this, when a work flow is executed through oozie for executing a python script which internally invoked a hive query(hive -e {query}), here in this hive query we are adding a custom jar using add jar {LOCAL PATH FOR JAR}, and created a temporary function for custom udf. And it looks ok till here. But when the query started executing with custom udf funtion it is failing with Distributed cache, File Not Found Exception which is looking for jar in the HDFS path instead of lookig in local path.

I am not sure if I am missing some configuration here.

Execption Trace:

> WARNING: org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.EventCounter is deprecated.
>   Please use org.apache.hadoop.log.metrics.EventCounter in all the
>   log4j.properties files. Execution log at:
>   /tmp/yarn/yarn_20131107020505_79b41443-b9f4-4d36-a0eb-4f0d79cd3ce9.log
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist:
>   hdfs://aa.bb.com:8020/opt/nfsmount/mypath/custom.jar
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:824)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:288)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:224)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestamps(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:93)
>   ..... .....

any help on this is highly appreciated.

Regards,
GHK.

Answer (score 1):

There are some few options. All the required jar should be in the classpath before you run hive query.

**option 1:** Add your custom jar by `<file>/hdfs/path/to/your/jar</file>` in oozie workflow

**option 2:** use attribute `--auxpath /local/path/to/your/jar` while calling your hive script in python. Eg: `hive --auxpath /local/path/to/your.jar -e {query}`

Comment: Yes, all the required jars should be in the class path, and in the .Q file we have "add jar {local jar path}" in the script. so while fetching the data only it is throwing the above exception. And if we execute that script manually with out oozie it works for me. The problem exists only with oozie. And even we have already tried the option2 listed above, still it didnt work for us, manually if we execute it works. So we are not sure why with oozie flow it is looking for hdfs path instead of local path.

Comment: Since Oozie workflow runs in map/reduce framework it will always look for jars in hdfs path. Upload your jar file to hdfs and set the property 'oozie.libpath' pointing to the location of that jar. Hope it works fine.

Comment: Yes I hope this works definitely, but how the same was working in CDH3 env, and the problem is with CDH4 env only.