# Hql Hive 2 unable to set auxpath using hql jdbc

Tags: hive, hiveql, cloudera-cdh

Referred :
[Hive query execution for custom udf is exepecting hdfs jar path instead of local path in CDH4 with Oozie flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19852632/hive-query-execution-for-custom-udf-is-exepecting-hdfs-jar-path-instead-of-local)

I have my jar placed on HDFS shared by two nodes. Strange that When I moved from Hive to Hive2 the following stopped working:

stmt.execute("set hive.aux.jars.path=/users/myHDFSPath");

Now it seems to have stopped working, please help

this is my code:

Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
        org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration conf = new   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration();
         System.setProperty("HADOOP_USER_NAME", "root");

```
    Connection conn1=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://hostname:10000/default","", "");
    System.out.println("connection done");
    final HiveConf hiveConf = new HiveConf(SessionState.class);
    ;
/*  String auxJars =    HiveConf.getVar(conf, HiveConf.ConfVars.HIVEAUXJARS);
 ClassLoader loader = Utilities.addToClassPath(hiveConf.getClassLoader(), StringUtils.split(auxJars, ","));*/
    Statement stmt=conn1.createStatement();
    stmt.execute("set hive.aux.jars.path=hdfs:/users/MyJars/MySerde");

    String createQry="create external Table sample1_new" +
            " ( Field0 STRING, Field1 STRING, Field2 STRING, Field3 STRING, Field4 STRING ) " +
            " row format serde 'com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.MySerde' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES " +
            " ( 'separatorChar' = '#' , 'quoteChar'= '\'') location '/users/sampleFile'";   
    stmt.execute(createQry);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Hive" and "Hive 2" exactly? Hive CLI and Beeline?

Comment: Which host is HiveServer2 running on? Does it have exactly the same Hadoop conf files as the edge node you are running Hive CLI? Did you try the fully qualified HDFS path e.g. `hdfs://hostel:666/users/some/where`?